# what is "Managed by Xcode" profile in ios provisioning portal and how was it created?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, provisioning

I created several profiles in IOS Provisioning Portal and suddenly a new one showed up with "Managed by Xcode" label. What is this? How was it created? What is it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually a Team profile.

It is created once you connect a device to your Mac and set it up as a development device inside the XCode.

If I remember right then XCode asks you if you want to ad it to your developer account and create a managed by XCode profile.
Not sure about that...